# How do I compare two strings recursively in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

Hi this is really easy to do non-recursively but how would I compare two strings to see if they are equal in Python? i.e if I had compile and compile it would return 0 and if I had compile and contrast it would return 1?

Comment: [How to ask minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: This really isn't a problem that can be (or should be!) solved by recursion. Simply check if they are equal using the `==` operator!

Comment: I imagine its being asked as an educational exercise

Answer (score 0):

At first we use `def compare(a,b)` for comparing in python.
It returns 0 for equal and 1 for a>b and -1 for a

Answer (score 0):

Well, lets see. I know you know how to do it iteratively, but it doesn't hurt to explicitly write it out:

```
def iterative_string_comparison(str1, str2):
    for char1,char2 in zip(str1, str2):
        if char1 != char2:
            return 1
    return 0
```

What are you really doing here? You're going through every character in both strings and comparing them to make sure they have the same value.

How would you do this recursively? I'll start you off with the pseudocode.

```
function recursive_string_comparison(str1, str2, index)
    if str1[index] != str2[index]
        return 1
    else
        if the index exceeds the length of either string
            return 0
        else
            return recursive_string_comparison(str1, str2, index + 1)
```

Also just a tip, you'll likely have more success having your questions answered in the future if you proofread to make sure its easy to understand what you're asking.